# How to change text in a button on hover with CSS in JS in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to make a button that changes from the text 'Done' to the text 'Update' on hover, ONLY when a true/false flag is true. I had a working method using onMouseOver to detect mouseover and then flip the value using state. However i've been asked to do it via CSS.

I'm having a hard time getting it done with just CSS.

```
<Button>
<span className={onHoverHide}>Done</span>
<span className={onHoverShow}>Update</span>
</Button>

CSS in JS

onHoverHide: {
 display:'auto',
  '&:hover':{
    display: 'none'
},
},

onHoverShow: {
 display:'none',
  '&:hover':1
    display: 'auto'
},
},
```

this will make the first span vanish when the TEXT is hovered, but won't make the 2ndary text appear. As well I need it to apply on mouseover to the button, not just the text.

How can I target the span in the button correctly?

```
onHoverbutton: {
 '&:hover': {
  '& span': {
   display: 'none'
```

was not successful when applied to the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `& $className` to target nested className in CSS-in-JS

```
onHoverbutton: {
  '&:hover': {
    '& $onHoverHide': {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `display: none;` to span, but both of your texts are a span.  Target the specific class of the one you want to hide.   Here's CSS code which can do this:

```
.onHoverShow {
  display: none;
}

button:hover .onHoverShow {
  display: block;
}

button:hover .onHoverHide {
  display: none;
}
```